# How does date command interact with timedatectl?

Tags: 16.04, time

I have two 16.04 servers.  The `timedatectl` on both machines shows that network time is ON, and NTP is synchronised.  Both are using UTC.  I then set the date to a random day next month using the `date` command.

On the first server, subsequent invocations of `date` show that the time change has indeed taken effect.  The `timedatectl` also shows the new date.  Network time is still on, but NTP synchronised = No.

On the second server, subsequent invocations of `date` do not show the new time, and neither does `timedatectl`.  Network time is still on, and so is NTP synchronised.

How does that work?  How should it work?

On both machines I did an `ps -la | grep ntp` to see if something else was managing the time, but nothing showed up.

The machine that accepts the new date and does not re-synch is running in virtual box, but I have guest additions installed so I imagine that would be compatible with NTP synch.  I am not sure about the details of the other machine - it is a Laravel Forge machine.

Comment: I answered most of this, but your **laravel forge** machine is a bit unknown.  would be good to print out what exactly happens on there when you run `sudo date -s ...` to set the system time.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a lot of good questions, I'll try to answer them, but I also suggest you read this [unix.stackexchange q/a on time on linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151547/linux-set-date-through-command-line).  It should provide you with some more in depth background than just the specific questions you are asking.

## Some Background Info

`timedatectl` is a program to interact with `systemd-timesyncd`, which is a lightweight NTP client provided by [`systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/).  Run `man timedatectl` to get an easy-to-read description of the program.  For instance `Network time on: yes` just means that the `systemd-timesyncd` service is enabled.  That's it.

This also explains why you won't see `ps faux |grep ntp` return anything. 
 The built-in ntp client is called `systemd-timesyncd`.

`date` is a program to query and manipulate the system date and time.  This is the time that your operating system thinks it is right now.  If you ran this with the `-s` argument, it will allow you to adjust your system time

## About your sample machines

**machine-1** you said is a machine running virtualbox.  This allows you setting the system clock normally (and even has a virtual hardware clock for you to mess with if you want).

What you describe sounds normal, you have skewed the clock a day, and the ntp client will no longer sync correctly.  This is why the `ntpdate` command existed for a long time in ubuntu, it's a one time command to bring the clock into alignment, and hand it over to an ntp client.  `systemd-timesyncd` now has this functionality built-in, but it only runs at startup, not all the time.

**machine-2** you said is a **laravel forge** machine.  I'm not sure what that is specifically.   If you run `sudo date -s '2018-04-18 12:00:00'`, does it let you do it?  What does it say?  It could be you don't have the ability to change the system clock on that server.  It could be a container (docker, lxd) of some kind, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

On the second server (where I was unable to change the date), issuing `sudo timedatectl set-ntp off` fixes the problem.  Later, when I want to re-synch the time, I issue `sudo timedatectl set-ntp on` and give it a few moments.  This makes sense.